# Codename one debug vs release preference values

Tags: codenameone

It's now that I am ready to make a release build, I would like to know if I should change the hardcoded preference setting values to release values?  Or is there config file I can use?  Please advise, as this is my very first app built on codename one framework.
Please provide some details what I should do to submit the release build to the app store and google play.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug and release have very little difference. The main difference is the certificate/provisioning used but in terms of compilation process it is almost identical.

Notice you can't install release builds, only submit it to itunes.

Comment: Thank you Shai.  I am also viewing your training courses on Udemy to understand this process.